# Can someone explain this cardinality participation constraint to me?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, cardinality

I'm reading my database book and it has this diagram:

[image]

I don't understand the second diagram, for "Employee - Works For - Department".

Is this diagram saying that at a MINIMUM only 1 employee, and a MAXIMUM of 1 employee can work for a MINIMUM of 1 department, and a MAXIMUM of many departments?

That doesn't make sense. Wouldn't this constrain of (1,1) limit the department to only having 1 employee working in it? Shouldn't it be this instead:

**Employee (1, N)  (1,N) Department**

If someone can explain this to me, that would be great. I suspect I am reading this wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second diagram, `(1,1)` indicates that each `EMPLOYEE` must appear once and only once in the relation. Since each tuple in the relation associates one `EMPLOYEE` with one `DEPARTMENT`, if an `EMPLOYEE` appears only once in the whole relation, they will be associated with only one `DEPARTMENT` in total. Hence, it means each `EMPLOYEE` works for a single `DEPARTMENT`.

The `(1,N)` constraint indicates that each `DEPARTMENT` must appear at least once in the relation, but can appear multiple times. Each appearance will be associated with an `EMPLOYEE`. In other words, it means a `DEPARTMENT` must have at least one, but can have multiple `EMPLOYEE`s.

For completeness, let me put the first diagram into the same terms. Each `EMPLOYEE` can appear once at most, which means an `EMPLOYEE` can manage one `DEPARTMENT` or none. Each `DEPARTMENT` must appear exactly once, so each `DEPARTMENT` must be managed by a single `EMPLOYEE`.